# How to get the data of Legend panel in grafana, eg min, max, avg of variable?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

Is there any way to get the min, max data shown in Legend panel of grafana? 
I have to extract those data for more than 600 variables over time so need any API or query or anything which will reduce manual efforts.
Let me know if any data needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the question asks how to show e.g. min, max and avg values of a graph in a legend of the panel, here is the answer: While editing a panel in Grafana, there is a bunch of tabs about in the middle of the display (including General, Metrics, Axes, Legend and so on...). From there you should choose the Legend tab where, under the Values title, you can select what is shown along with the legend of your graph. Here is [a link to Grafana's Graph Panel Legend documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/panels/graph/#legend) where you can read more.

If the question is asking how to fetch those values for some other external use, then I don't know.

Comment: Hi nezzzzzz, I need the data shown on legend in a sheet/file. The data is visible in the legend panel. I want to extract data from grafana and save it in some file.